# PHP include header and footer with different plugins on some pages

Tags: php, header, include, footer

I am building a website with php and it has 20 pages. In the homepage
    I would like to have a slider and some other plugins which I include them
    in the head. In the footer I link also some JS files.
    When we use php we have header.php and footer.php
    Some of the plugins are not needed on some pages but the header.php
    and footer.php is included on those pages. Is there a way to remove
    those plugins on those specific pages? or I have to include everything
    even if they are not needed? Also I would like to add some other plugins
    in some of the pages that are not needed in the Home Page. Should I create multiple header.php and footer.php and include them when necessary?
    What is the solution to this problem?

Thanks.

```
Example:

Home Page those are needed:

Header.php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin01.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin02.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin03.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin04.css">

Footer.php
<script src="plugin01.js"></script>
<script src="plugin02.js"></script>
<script src="plugin03.js"></script>
<script src="plugin04.js"></script>


Random Page:

I need only

header.php 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin01.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin02.css">

footer.php
<script src="plugin01.js"></script>
<script src="plugin02.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why don't you only put only the common css in your header and common js in your footer and then add the extra ones as an when you need them?

Comment: How can u do that since we close <head>ALL PLUGINS</head> in the header.php

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to define for each page its required plugins (resources).
In the header and footer files, simply loop through that array and call the resources.

It's a bit more work but it's a better organised method and in case you'll have in the future a new page with other plugins, instead of writing patched, you'll easily update it using this mechanism.

**PageX.php**

```
//$this_page = 'pageX';
$plugins = array(
 'css' => array(
   'pluginName1' => 'plugin-name-1.css',
   'pluginName2' => 'plugin-name-2.css', 
 ),
 'js' => array(
   'pluginName1' => 'plugin-name-1.js'
 )
);

require_once 'header.php;
//....
//...
require_once 'footer.php';
```

**Header.php**

```
foreach($plugins['css'] as $name => $resource_url){
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$resource_url.'">';
}
```

**Footer.php**

```
foreach($plugins['js'] as $name => $resource_url){
  echo '<script src="'.$resource_url.'"></script>';
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution!! But a big typo - instead of css, js links are written in Header.php and vice versa.

Comment: @T.Shah You're right. Been a while since then hhh
Edited.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create a helper function to assist with loading required assets and then have a common header.php / footer.php like this:

**helpers.php**

```
<?php

function loadStyles($assets = array()) {
    foreach ($assets as $asset) {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'. $asset .'.css">'."\r\n";
    }
}

function loadScripts($assets = array()) {
    foreach ($assets as $asset) {
        echo '<script src="'. $asset .'.js"></script>'."\r\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Then, update your `header.php` like this:

```
<?php

// Load required stylehseets for this page 
if (isset($styleAssets)) {
    loadStyles($styleAssets);
}

// Rest of your common header stuff here

?>
```

Then do something similar with `footer.php` like this:

```
<?php

// Load required scripts for this page
if (isset($scriptAssets)) {
    loadScripts($scriptAssets);
}

// Rest of your common footer stuff here

?>
```

Then you put it all together like this. For example, this is your "home.php" page:

```
<?php

// Load helpers
require 'helpers.php'

// Define required styles for this page
$styleAssets = array(
    'plugin01',
    'plugin02',
    'plugin03',
    'plugin04'
);

// Load header
require 'header.php'

// Rest of the "home" page code goes here

// Define required scripts for this page
$scriptAssets = array(
    'plugin01',
    'plugin02',
    'plugin03',
    'plugin04'
);

// Load footer
require 'footer.php'

?>
```

Now, for another `random.php` page, you simply re-use the script like this:

```
<?php

// Load helpers
require 'helpers.php'

// Define required styles for this page
$styleAssets = array(
    'plugin01',
    'plugin02'
);

// Load header
require 'header.php'

// Rest of the "random" page code goes here

// Define required scripts for this page
$scriptAssets = array(
    'plugin01',
    'plugin02'
);

// Load footer
require 'footer.php'

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **Header.php** you can check for the current page.

```
if( basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'homepage.php')
{ ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin01.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin02.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin03.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugin04.css">
<?php 
}
```